# Angular (1.2) $sce blocking my blob src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to solve a ng-src trust issue

```
angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope, $sce) {

  // Construct a dummy blob Url 
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 100;
  canvas.height = 100;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    $scope.src = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    // works...
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = $scope.src;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  });


}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DqRrzMv4YzIi0Hd1Zubu?p=preview

Comment: I am afraid it is not clear what you are asking here. Could you please make the expected behaviour and the erroneous behaviour explicit in the question?

Comment: Trying to use ng-src instead of body append. But angular adds unsafe protocol in the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself

```
app.config( ['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider){   
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(blob):/);
}]);
```